# Transform multi-column, multi-row into a multi-column, single-row dataframe

Tags: r

I'll preface this by saying I've trolled the web and attempted several different code pieces (base R, dplyr, tidyr) but I cannot quite get where I need to be. I have a dataframe of a fixed number of columns...

```
   client_id    question    brand_id
      2           101          7
      7           101          4
      7           101          97
      7           101          5
      7           101          10
      7           101          97
      7           101          14
      7           101           7
      9           101           6
      9           101          97
      9           101          16
      9           101           2
      9           101           7
```

...that I need to transform into...

```
 client_id question bid1 bid2 bid3 bid4 bid5 bid6 bid7
   2         101     7                      
   7         101     4    97   5    10   97   14    7
   9         101     6    97   16    2    7
```

...whereby each row can have a varying number of columns but would never exceed 12 columns. The communities assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: please include what you really have tried

Comment: `library(tidyverse); df %>% group_by(client_id, question) %>% mutate(var = paste0('bid', row_number())) %>% spread(var, brand_id)`, but this is very likely a bad idea, as it makes your data less tidy. Grouping or nesting is probably what you're driving at, but more context would be necessary.

Comment: @alistaire      thanks for the insight, grouping by the client_id and question.The challenge is the variability in the columns.

Comment: Thus why this is a bad idea. Step back: what are you trying to do that made you want your data in this format?

Comment: @alistaire      For an end client who needs the data in this structure, each row represents a client_id. If the columns were fixed I think the ask would be more straight-forward.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your data as a data.table:

```
dcast(temp[,.(paste0("bid",1:(.N)), question,brand_id),
           by=client_id], ...~V1)
```

Maybe there is a simpler way.